# mysql - If 2 or more members picked the same team return the member which guessed closest to the score

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table which recorded the selection / picks from members they thought were going to win a sports match.

Furthermore **consider each pick is correct** for the sake of simplicity.

[image]
[image]

I need to find a way to retrieve the member_nr of the person who guessed/picked the result correct. However:

**If 2 or more members picked the same team *return the member which guessed closest to the score***

**If 2 or more members picked the *same team with the same score return both members***

I have managed to write the following code but it does not return the correct results AND is not effective if it needs to return more than 1 winner

```
((SELECT pick_id,member_nr,event_id,pool_id,pick,score, 10-score AS diff
from picks
WHERE pick = '$winner'
AND score < '$winScore'
ORDER BY score DESC

)
UNION ALL
(SELECT pick_id,member_nr,event_id,pool_id,pick,score, score-10 AS diff
FROM picks
WHERE pick = '$winner'
AND score >= '$winScore'
ORDER BY score

)
)As tmp
order by diff
";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With subquery it's something like this:

```
select * from picks where pick = '$winner' and
    abs(score-$winScore) = (select min(abs(score-$winScore)) from picks 
    where pick = '$winner');
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for answer, Secondly I believe you are on the right path. However your query keeps on returning no results even if I modify it and 'hardcode' $winner and $winScore it still comesback empty....

Comment: Sorry for blind code, updated my answer. Now should be correct.

Comment: lets give it a go Ill let you know soon

Comment: You can add as many comparisons as you like to the query :) But remember that you probably need to add both to main **and** sub-query.

Comment: I accepted your answer working 100% thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The following gets the winning score:

```
SELECT score
from picks
WHERE pick = '$winner'
ORDER BY abs('$winScore' - score) ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Your question is a bit tricky because you don't know how many rows will be returned.  That means that `LIMIT` cannot be used for the final query.

You can incorporate the above into a query to get all the winners:

```
select p.*
from picks p cross join
     (SELECT score
      from picks
      where pick = '$winner'
      order by abs('$winScore' - score) ASC
      limit 1
     ) winning
where p.pick = '$winner' and
      p.score = winning.score;
```